# How to walk through a directory tree returning relative paths without using `forfiles`?

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, path, relative-path

The command `forfiles` provides the capability to walk through a directory tree recursively, each iteration returning a path relative to the given root directory when using its variable `@relpath` (each item prefixed with `.\`, and unfortunately double-quoted):

```
forfiles /S /P "D:\data" /S /M "*" /C "cmd /C echo @relpath"
```

Is there a way to do exactly this without `forfiles` (but without the surrounding quotes preferrably)?
Actually I want to avoid any self-coded assembly or rebuild of the relative path, if somehow possible.

---

The following lines both provide absolute paths only (even appending `\` or `\.` to the root path or prefixing the mask with `.\` does not change anything):

```
for /R "D:\Data" %L in ("*.*") do echo %L
cd /D "D:\Data" & for /R "." %L in ("*.*") do echo %L
```

Also parsing the output of `dir /S /B "D:\Data"` with a `for /F` satement does not do what I want, because `dir` returns absolute paths as soon as the switch `/S` is given.

Comment: Is this specific to Windows/batch?

Comment: Yes, it's Windows-related (I'll add the tag); it's not necessarily related to batch as you can execute all commands directly in the command line interpreter (that's what I did, see my `for` `%L` syntax which should read `%%L` if used in batch);

Comment: Thanks for down-voting without telling why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```dos
xcopy /l /s . "%temp%" | find ".\"
```

And no, nothing is copied, we just request the list of the files to copy (the `/l` switch).

The `find` command is included just to remove the footer with the count of matching files.

Comment: Excellent idea using `xcopy`, @MCND! An additional benefit for me is that a pure files list with no directories is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Based on @MCND's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320364/5047996), I provide the full code I am going to use (started from the root directory):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %L in ('xcopy /L /S /E /I /Y /C "*.*" "%TEMP%"') do echo %L
```

The output is a list of pure file paths relative to the current directory.

Since source is a file pattern `*.*` rather than the current directory `.` here, every listed relative file path is prefixed with the current drive (for instance, `D:`; there is no more `.\`). That is why I am using the `for /F` option `delims=:`. There will not be any other colon(s) in each remaining line, so using `tokens=2` is safe. This `for /F` application filters out the `xcopy`'s summary line, so no additional `find` is needed. Every line begins with a drive letter, so the default `eol=;` option does not matter.

To use this within a batch file, exchange `%L` by `%%L`.